# Regex to validate username in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Following is the regex that I tried to validate against the below mentioned criteria, but in some cases its failing. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**Regex-**

```
/[a-z]|\d|\_{4, 16}$/.test(username)
```

**Criteria -**

Allowed characters are:

- lowercase letters
- Numbers
- Underscore
- Length should be between 4 and 16 characters (both included).

Code

```js
function validateUsr(username) {
  res =  /[a-z]|\d|\_{4, 16}$/.test(username) 
  return res
}

console.log(validateUsr('asddsa')); // Correct Output - true
console.log(validateUsr('a')); // Correct Output - false
console.log(validateUsr('Hass')); // Correct Output - false
console.log(validateUsr('Hasd_12assssssasasasasasaasasasasas')); // Correct Output - false
console.log(validateUsr('')); // Correct Output - false
console.log(validateUsr('____')); // Correct Output - true
console.log(validateUsr('012')); // Correct Output - false
console.log(validateUsr('p1pp1')); // Correct Output - true
console.log(validateUsr('asd43 34')); // Correct Output - false
console.log(validateUsr('asd43_34')); // Correct Output - true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may join the patterns to a single character class and apply the limiting quantifier to the class, not just to the `_` pattern. Note the space is meaningful inside a pattern, and `{4, 16}` matches a `{4, 16}` string, it is not parsed as a quantifier.

You may use

```js
var regex = /^[a-z\d_]{4,16}$/;
function validateUsr(username) {
  return regex.test(username) 
}

console.log(validateUsr('asddsa')); // Correct Output - true
console.log(validateUsr('a')); // Correct Output - false
console.log(validateUsr('Hass')); // Correct Output - false
console.log(validateUsr('Hasd_12assssssasasasasasaasasasasas')); // Correct Output - false
console.log(validateUsr('')); // Correct Output - false
console.log(validateUsr('____')); // Correct Output - true
console.log(validateUsr('012')); // Correct Output - false
console.log(validateUsr('p1pp1')); // Correct Output - true
console.log(validateUsr('asd43 34')); // Correct Output - false
console.log(validateUsr('asd43_34')); // Correct Output - true
```

The `^[a-z\d_]{4,16}$` - [see its demo](https://regex101.com/r/8l57BQ/1) - pattern means:

- `^` - start of string
- `[` - start of a character class:

  - `a-z`  - ASCII lowercase letters
  - `\d` - ASCII digit
  - `_` - an underscore
- `]{4,16}` - end of the class, repeat four through sixteen times
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: What is the meaning of `^` in `/^[a-z\d_]{4,16}$/` ?

Comment: @Nesh I added details.